# java prefix/postfix operators

Tags: java, operators, expression, lvalue

Why I'm getting an error for:

```
int i=0;
++i++;
```

What does this error mean?

```
  unexpected type ++i++;                    
  required: variable  
  found:    value
```

Comment: `++i` resolves to a value. You cannot apply the operator `++` to a value.

Comment: There is no type with combination of prefix and postfix ++i++;

Comment: I think this is quite interesting question considering the answers. Why downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is about lvalue (left value). Lvalue is, what on the left side of an "=" stay can. Also, to what you can give a value. For example, you can't give a value to "4", but you can to give a value to "i". The expressions of variables aren't just so lvalues (with the exception of some very esoteric programming language).

If you write "++i++", it will be interpreted as (++i)++ or ++(i++). "i" is an lvalue, but "i++" or "++i" not, because they are expressions.

In C++, with some tricky operator overloading and reference-variable tricks, the C++ compiler could be tricked to handle this correctly.

Comment: It's the quality/effort put into the question that is getting downvoted IMO.

Comment: It will *always* be interpreted as  ++(i++) due to associativity but +1 for talking about lvalues.

Answer (score 5):

`++i` or `i++` can be used on variable, but not on value so

```
i++
++i
```

is OK, but

```
2++
++2
```

is not.

Also result of `++i` or `i++` is not variable `i` but its original *value* (like when `i=1`, `i++` would change `i` to `2` but would return `1`). So even doing something like

```
(++i)++
```

would be incorrect because after `++i` you would just try to use `++` on result of `++i` which could be for example `2`. This means you would try to perform `2++`.

Similar problem exists in case of `++(i++)`

Answer (score 4):

Both prefix and suffix versions require the operation to be performed on a variable, not a value. You can increment a variable `i` with `i++` or `++i` but you can't increment `5` or `3.14`.

`++i++` means that you're trying to increment `i` by one and then increment the resulting **value** by one. There's the error.

Answer (score 4):

Since `++` postfix and prefix have the same precedence, we need to resort to *associativity* to figure out what is going on.

The associativity of `++` is right to left.

That means that, conceptually, `i++` happens first. But this, of course, is a fixed **value** (it's the value of `i` prior to incrementation). Therefore the prefix `++` is going to fail as it cannot operate on a fixed value.

Comment: Is this actually legal but undefined behavior in C++? I would have thought it was illegal there as well.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: you're correct: it will not compile in C++ (not an lvalue). I was thinking more about all the i++ + ++i stuff that you often see which is UB in C++ but well-defined in Java. Agree that my answer is inprecise so will amend.

Answer (score 1):

`++i++;` is not valid. You can only do one at a time. `++` in prefix or `++` in postfix.
I see that you are trying to increment the value by two. You can do this as follows:

```
i++ // will post-increment the value of i
++i // will pre-increment the value of i
```

`i++` is the same as `i = i + 1` or `i += 1`. Hence, you need some variable to which this value can be saved, as pointed out by  Sotirios Delimanolis in the comments.